# Filtering Events in Event Grid

Tags: azure-eventgrid

I have added an Event Subscription on my Storage Account which will trigger on the Blob Created event. But I want to ensure that the Event grid is only triggered if I upload my blob in a particular Container/directory or it should be uploaded only if it has the mentioned prefix. I have tried using the filters present in Event Grid

Filter Value

> /blobServices/default/containers/MyContainer/blobs/Test

> /blobServices/default/containers/MyContainer/

[image: Filter Image]

[image: Blob Containers]

but both of the filters doesn't seem to be working as my EventGrid doesn't trigger any events.

PS I have read this documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003556#filtering-events and still unable to achieve what I require

Comment: based on the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage#microsoftstorageblobcreated-event the filter value must be **/blobServices/default/containers/MyContainer/blobs/Test**  or **/blobServices/default/containers/MyContainer/** (missing a slash charackter on the begiinnig value)

Comment: Hey Roman, Sorry I missed to add the / in my Question. I have added it in my filter

Comment: Are you receiving an event without the filtering?

Comment: Yes Roman. Without the filtering I am receiving the events

Comment: Can you show the subscription screen snippet on the Filters tab?

Comment: I have attached the Images. Please do check

Comment: based on your comment, that it's working without the filtering and the filter screen snippet, your subscriber should be received the event, when the blob with the name started as **Test** has been created in the blob container *rawdata*, for instances, files as: Test.json, TestXXXX.zzz, Test/XXX/yyy.zzz, ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Storage Account is Version 2.(it's really important check it)

if it's V1 you can change it in your Storage Account like this:

[image]

use this as a filter for your specific Container.

```
/blobServices/default/containers/MyContainer/
```